# Exclude properties from Apex class when serializing to JSON

Tags: apex, json, class

Is it possible to delete class properties dynamically in Apex

Example:

```
public class BananaHolder() {
   public boolean isRipe;
   public boolean isDelicious;
   public integer somePropertyThatShouldntBeSentOverJson;
   public string JSON() { return JSON.serialize(this); }
}

BananaHolder banana = getRandomBanana();
// Delete somePropertyThatShouldntBeSentOverJson property
String jsonString = banana.JSON();
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could always make the offending property transient, then it won't be included in the JSON (link to [transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) docs)

```
public class BananaHolder {
   public boolean isRipe;
   public boolean isDelicious;
   public transient integer somePropertyThatShouldntBeSentOverJson;
   public string JSON() {
        return JSON.serialize(this);
    }
}

BananaHolder banana = new BananaHolder();
String jsonString = banana.JSON(); 
System.debug(jsonString);
```

returns

> DEBUG|{"isRipe":null,"isDelicious":null}

Comment: That should do the trick

Comment: one thing to note, serialization includes private variables, so take care to use transient with those if you don't want them output in a public rest service accidentally